# "Makes Pointer from Integer without a Cast" - How do I satisfy GCC?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, x11

I'm writing my first X11 applications in C and I've run into a major problem while trying to retrieve the size of my applications window.

`temp.c:30:2 warning: passing argument 3 of 'XGetGeometry' makes pointer from integer without a cast`

I know this is just a warning, but it still results in a **segfault** which isn't fun.  Here is my code:

```
static void loop();
static void initialize();
static void cleanUp();
static void run();

/* Variables */

static int screenNumber;
unsigned long White;
unsigned long Black;
long eventMask;
static Display *currentDisplay;
static Window currentWindow;
static unsigned int windowWidth;
static unsigned int windowHeight;
static GC graphicsController;
static XEvent XEvents;

void loop() {
        XGetGeometry(currentDisplay, currentWindow, DefaultRootWindow(currentDisplay), NULL, NULL, &windowWidth, &windowHeight, NULL, NULL);

        XDrawLine(currentDisplay, currentWindow, graphicsController, 0, 0, (int)windowWidth, (int)windowHeight);
        XDrawLine(currentDisplay, currentWindow, graphicsController, 0, (int)windowHeight, (int)windowWidth, 0);
}

void initialize() {
        currentDisplay = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        screenNumber = DefaultScreen(currentDisplay);

        White = WhitePixel(currentDisplay, screenNumber);
        Black = BlackPixel(currentDisplay, screenNumber);

        currentWindow = XCreateSimpleWindow(    currentDisplay,
                                                DefaultRootWindow(currentDisplay),
                                                0, 0,
                                                500, 500,
                                                0, Black,
                                                White);

        XMapWindow(currentDisplay, currentWindow);
        XStoreName(currentDisplay, currentWindow, "rGot - X11");

        eventMask = StructureNotifyMask;
        XSelectInput(currentDisplay, currentWindow, eventMask);

        do{
                XNextEvent(currentDisplay, &XEvents);
        }while(XEvents.type != MapNotify);

        graphicsController = XCreateGC(currentDisplay, currentWindow, 0, NULL);

        XSetForeground(currentDisplay, graphicsController, Black);
}

void run() {
        eventMask = ButtonPressMask|ButtonReleaseMask;
        XSelectInput(currentDisplay, currentWindow, eventMask);
        do{
                XNextEvent(currentDisplay, &XEvents);
                loop();
        }while(1==1);
}

void cleanUp() {
        XDestroyWindow(currentDisplay, currentWindow);
        XCloseDisplay(currentDisplay);
}

int main(){
        initialize();
        run();
        cleanUp();
        return 0;
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong with my pointers 'n such, but I'm fairly new to this...  Here is my setup:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Compiling with: `gcc tempc -o temp -lX11`

***For those finding this later - my initial attempts to utilize `XGetGeometry` were completely wrong!***

To correctly use it, I had to do the following:

`XGetGeometry(currentDisplay, currentWindow, &currentRoot, &windowOffsetX, &windowOffsetY, &windowWidth, &windowHeight, &windowBorderWidth, &windowDepth);`

This was based off of my findings [here](http://menehune.opt.wfu.edu/Kokua/Irix_6.5.21_doc_cd/usr/share/Insight/library/SGI_bookshelves/SGI_Developer/books/XLib_PG/sgi_html/ch03.html#EX-1002-3-4).

Comment: The question you need to answer is *why* are you calling `XGetGeometry`. You cannot make the call correct without figuring out what do you want to do with it.

Comment: @n.m., My goal is to get the size of my window.  I was able to get the size of the screen, but I need to know what size my actual window is.

Comment: Aw sorry, I misread your code. Missed `&windowWidth, &windowHeight` somehow. So this part is correct and I've just made myself look stupid. The only problem was that the root window is the return argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the docs for the two functions, `DefaultRootWindow()` returns a `Window` while `XGetGeometry()` expects a `Window*` for the third argument. So as the warning says, you're passing a normal type where a pointer to that type is expected.

Comment: In particular, the third argument to `XGetGeometry` should be a pointer to a variable that it will write the window handle of the root window to -- an output from the fuction, not an input.

Comment: +1, I keep forgetting that X11 is largely based on `XID` which is an unsigned long integer, the error messages aren't as telling as they would be with a separate type :)

Comment: Thanks a ton!  Admittedly, I was, for some reason, stuck thinking that my &windowWidth arguments were wrong.  Thanks for clarifying the error message!  :)